# CUDA accelerate Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, gpgpu

I am trying to visualize the evolution of my data by looping through it, plotting it, saving it as an image, then reconstructing the sequence of images into a video via FFmpeg.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['seconds'] = seconds
df['data'] = data

for x in range(2000, len(data)):
    start = x-2000
    end = x-1
    plt.figure(figsize=[15,20])
    
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(df['data'].iloc[:end])
    plt.title(f"Observation: {end}  Time: {df['seconds'].iloc[end]} seconds", fontsize=30, ha='center')
    plt.xlim(right=len(data))
    plt.xlabel('Observation',fontsize = 20)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize = 20)
    plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
    plt.grid()

    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(df['data'].iloc[start:end])
    plt.xlabel('Observation',fontsize = 20)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize = 20)
    plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
    plt.grid()

    plt.savefig(f"dataset/{end}.jpg")
    plt.close()
```

First subplot is an expanding window while the second subplot is a rolling window.

len(data) comes out to around half a million elements and I project this will take FOREVER for one render, and I have several of these I need to do.

I have a Nvidia GPU and was wondering if this can be CUDA accelerated.  It seems Nvidia has something called 'Anaconda Accelerate' but their site has dead links:
https://developer.nvidia.com/anaconda-accelerate
So I don't suppose this is offerred anymore.

Is there a way to accelerate the plotting and saving of MPL plots?  This would help immensely!

Thank you

Comment: you dont need to plot many figures, you can use matplotlib animation, and save to movies. In matplotlib animation, you only need to update data, no plot, draw, save close cycle.